# Return xml sequences where an attribute doesn't contain a specific character

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Consider the following simple XML:

```
<xml>
  <customer name="Max">
    <email address="me@you.com" />
  </customer>
  <customer name="Erik">
    <email address="erik@your-mom.com" />
  </customer>
  <customer name="Brent">
    <email address="brentcom" />
  </customer>
</xml>
```

I want to get a list of `<Customer>` sequences where the `address` attribute of the `<email>` item does *not* contain an `@`.

So, I want output that looks like:

```
<customer name="Brent">
  <email address="brentcom" />
</customer>
```

[mcve](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<xml>
<customer name="Max"><email address="me@you.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Erik"><email address="erik@your-mom.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Brent"><email address="brentcom" /></customer>
</xml>';
```

This query:

```
SELECT WithValidEmail = @x.query('/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@")]')
    , WithInvalidEmail = @x.query('/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@")] = False');
```

Returns:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║            WithValidEmail             ║ WithInvalidEmail ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ <email address="me@you.com" />        ║                  ║
║ <email address="erik@your-mom.com" /> ║ false            ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

This query:

```
SELECT WithInValidEmail = @x.query('/xml/customer/email')
WHERE @x.exist('/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@")]') = 0;
```

Returns:

```
╔══════════════════╗
║ WithInValidEmail ║
╚══════════════════╝
    (no results)
```

The `WHERE` clause in the query above is eliminating the entire set of XML because at least a single sequence exists where the email address contains an "@" sign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to use the `nodes` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) to get right to the `address` attribute and check for your `@` sign.

The problem with the way you're looking now is that it's only checking that *any* email address has an `@` in it. Parsing the XML nodes out lets you check individual emails for it.

```
DECLARE @x XML
    = '<xml>
<customer name="Max"><email address="me@you.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Erik"><email address="erik@your-mom.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Brent"><email address="brentcom" /></customer>
</xml>';


SELECT x.c.value('@address', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [email]
FROM   @x.nodes('/xml/customer/email') AS x(c)
WHERE  x.c.exist('@address[contains(., "@")]') = 0;
```

If you need to query an actual table with an XML column like this, you'd just `CROSS APPLY` the nodes method like thusly:

```
SELECT x.c.value('@address', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [email]
FROM @x_table AS xt
CROSS APPLY xt.x.nodes('/xml/customer/email') AS x(c)
WHERE  x.c.exist('@address[contains(., "@")]') = 0;
```

If you want to bring all the `<customer>...</customer>` XML for that "row" back, you can walk the axis back. Just be aware that walking *back* can make performance a bit woogy for large XML blocks.

```
SELECT x.c.query('..')
FROM @x_table AS xt
CROSS APPLY xt.x.nodes('/xml/customer/email') AS x(c)
WHERE  x.c.exist('@address[contains(., "@")]') = 0;
```

Another way of doing it is:

```
SELECT @x.query('/xml/customer[email/@address[not(contains(., "@"))]]') answer
```

Moving the square brackets to wrap around the email node effectively make that the `WHERE` clause applied to the `customer` node.  Translating this XQuery to English looks like:

> Get me all `xml/customer` nodes with an `email` node which has an `address` attribute
>   which does not contain the `@` symbol

Answer (score 4):

You were oh so close. You were definitely on the right track with using the `.query()` function and using the `contains` XQuery function. What you got wrong was:

1. Putting the `= False` *outside* of the `[...]` (meaning, it was not part of the `contains()` expression)
2. Using the word `False` instead of the function `false()`
3. Not specifying the parent node by adding `/..` to the end of the path (so that the result will include the `<customer>` element and not just the `<email>` element)

Correcting those three things results in the following XQuery expression that gets you what you are wanting:

```
'/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@") = false()]/..'
```

Putting that into your original example from the question gives you:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<xml>
<customer name="Max"><email address="me@you.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Erik"><email address="erik@your-mom.com" /></customer>
<customer name="Brent"><email address="brentcom" /></customer>
</xml>';

SELECT
@x.query('/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@")]/..') AS [WithValidEmail],
@x.query('/xml/customer/email[contains(@address, "@")=false()]/..') AS [WithInvalidEmail;
```

That query returns the following result set of a single row with two XML fields:

```
WithValidEmail                            |     WithInvalidEmail
```

```xml
<customer name="Max">                     |     <customer name="Brent">
  <email address="me@you.com" />          |       <email address="brentcom" />
</customer>                               |     </customer>
<customer name="Erik">                    |
  <email address="erik@your-mom.com" />   |
</customer>                               |
```

This is probably more efficient than breaking the document out with the `.nodes()` function since it can parse the XML in a single shot and not need to start and stop the parser per each node.

The other benefit of keeping it within `.query()` is that you get a single XML document returned. So, if you receive an XML document / value containing multiple nodes worth of stuff, you can maintain the scalar value approach of it being a single entity without having to reconstruct the resulting nodes back into a document again. This also lets you use it in a subquery / CTE without changing the number of expected rows being returned.